# How can I make my Kindle as writeable File-System?

Tags: filesystem, read-only, kindle

I have tried to move a pdf file from my Ubuntu Desktop to Kindle 10th generation Device but It shown me

```
uniteworld@inspiron-3442:/media/uniteworld/Kindle/Documents$ mv /home/uniteworld/Downloads/David_Griffiths_Introduction_to_elementary_particles.pdf /media/uniteworld/Kindle/Documents
mv: inter-device move failed: '/home/uniteworld/Downloads/David_Griffiths_Introduction_to_elementary_particles.pdf' to '/media/uniteworld/Kindle/Documents/David_Griffiths_Introduction_to_elementary_particles.pdf'; unable to remove target: Read-only file system
```

Then I tried

```
root@inspiron-3442:/media/uniteworld# chmod +w Kindle
chmod: changing permissions of 'Kindle': Read-only file system
root@inspiron-3442:/media/uniteworld# chmod 755 Kindle
chmod: changing permissions of 'Kindle': Read-only file system
```

Now my queary is How can I change the file-system into writable file system.I am aware that some past I did move the file from my Ubuntu desktop into that Kindle Device.I don't know What I did wrong so that it is happening now.Any kind help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
~$ mount
```

output parts

```
 /dev/sdb on /media/yourusername/Kindle type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Then type

```
sudo fsck.vfat -r /dev/sdb
```

output

```
[sudo] password for yourusername: 
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action
?
```

Type `1`
And follow the instructions.